# Symfony2 application architecture

Tags: symfony

I want to actually implement two applications.

1. Application (server 1)

A management application to manage users and buildings. CRUD Controller for users, roles and buildings. To use this application an login is required. Analyse answers / results from questionnaires which will be filled in appplication 2.

2. Application (server 2)

   - Login with the user names which will be created in application one
   - Document Exchange bundle. Users can share documents
   - Questionnaire bundle, users can create questionnaire
   - Other users filling of questionnaires

Not every user can use every bundle in application 2. Only users with specified roles can use a bundle, the user roles will be defined in application 1.

I need an idea how I could realize the data exchange in such a case? Because application 2 require the user, roles from database of the first application. In the ideal case, I do not want data redundancy.

The first application i implement in symfony2 and i'm not sure whether to share a good idea the applications or is it better idea to integrate the bundles from application 2 in application one?

Can someone give me tips?

Comment: Is a must to have 2 different APPs?

Comment: No it is not a must have. Only an initial idea for the maintainability in the future. But maybe the maintainability in one APP and different bundles is also good, i have not an experience in this case which is the better way. Do you recommend one APP?

Comment: uhm there isn't the right answer in this cases, I write the simple solution to manage access.

Answer (score 0):

The easier solution could be done with the use of one App. The [Security Component of Symfony2](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/security/index.html) can manage different [roles](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/security/authorization.html#roles) and access to specific action or bundle. Moreover you can use [JMSSecurityExtraBundle Annotations](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSecurityExtraBundle/master/annotations) to simpler your work.

Comment: Ok i do not know this bundle before. I implement custom voters to handle the role and access. This bundle loook great. Maybe i can use this in future for new APPs. Thank you for your support